# Can I run a JUnit Plug-in Test with Gradle

Tags: junit, eclipse-plugin, gradle

I'm trying to figure out if and how I can run JUnit Plug-in Tests with Gradle. To be perfectly honest I don't fully understand the difference between a standard JUnit Test and a JUnit Plug-in Test. I'm am working on a pre-existing project that has tests of both sorts.

Right now when I attempt to build and run the tests with gradle it reports various errors. When running the tests using eclipse all tests pass. I will post error messages if someone thinks they will be helpful but I feel as though they are the result of attempting to run these tests as JUnit tests as opposed to a JUnit Plug-in test.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: You'd have to clarify what you mean by "JUnit Plug-in Test".

Comment: I'm piecing together info as I go. But this plug-in is based on the OSGI framework.

Comment: Sounds like something Eclipse/Equinox specific. Gradle doesn't come with support for that. Perhaps there is a third-party plugin (I'm not aware of one).

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser Okay thanks for the info. If I find something useful I will post an update.

Comment: Is there any news on this subject? I face the same issues currently.